# 550 views.py: Permission denied

Tags: linux, django, ftp

I have a problem with the permissions in a Django project.
I create the project via SSH and everything works fine. But when I try to edit the files with FTP, filezilla gives me this error:

```
550 views.py: Permission denied
```

I tried this and doesn't work:

```
chmod -R g+w testproject/
chgrp -R www-data testproject/
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you able to read file via FTP?

Comment: Yes I can read, but not edit or delete, and only happens in files created with SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. I tried `sudo chmod -R 777 FILENAME` and it works.
But I found something else that works too and is safer.

```
chown ftpuser testproject/ -R
```

Hope it helps someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to change the permissions or edit the file then it is likely the SSH user doesn't have the right write permission or filezilla does not should I say. Check the Owner/Group portion of the file to see who owns it.

You need to define the FTP users in FileZilla Server Interface on your server.

As a quick fix to test try if Linux `sudo chmod -R 777 FILENAME`

Another thing is this apache? Is it just ssh? Check you host...

```
<Directory /*>
    AllowOverwrite on
</Directory>
```